# Convert JSON (from Sentry) to HTML with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, sentry

I want to learn TypeScript.

I have a JSON dictionary returned by the sentry method `event_from_exception()` (Python).

I would like to format it as nice HTML with expandable local variables and pre_ and post_context. The result should look roughly like this:

[image: traceback-in-django-debug-view]

Here is an example json:

```
{
  "exception": {
    "values": [
      {
        "stacktrace": {
          "frames": [
            {
              "function": "main", 
              "abs_path": "/home/modlink_cok_d/src/sentry-json.py", 
              "pre_context": [
                "from sentry_sdk.utils import event_from_exception", 
                "", 
                "def main():", 
                "    local_var = 1", 
                "    try:"
              ], 
              "lineno": 9, 
              "vars": {
                "exc": "ValueError()", 
                "local_var": "1"
              }, 
              "context_line": "        raise ValueError()", 
              "post_context": [
                "    except Exception as exc:", 
                "        event, info = event_from_exception(sys.exc_info(), with_locals=True)", 
                "        print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))", 
                "", 
                "main()"
              ], 
              "module": "__main__", 
              "filename": "sentry-json.py"
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "type": "ValueError", 
        "value": "", 
        "module": "exceptions", 
        "mechanism": null
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "level": "error"
}
```

How could this be done with TypeScript?

Comment: this question doesn't really have what is required - you should show what you've tried, etc. 'with typescript' doesn't help - is there a framework involved? It seems like you're just trying to get someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: @David this is my first "toy" project with TypeScript. I have never used the language before. That's why I have not tried anything yet. Up to now there is no other framework involved. I don't want someone else to do this. I want some hints how this could be solved.

Comment: do you have an idea of how you'd do it using JavaScript? That should definitely steer you in the right direction for how to do it with TypeScript.

Comment: @David no, I have no idea how to do this in JS. I once used XSLT to transform XML from one format to an other XML format. But this was no fun. I think XSLT is too complicated.

Comment: I am confused about one aspect of this question: Do you want to have a CLI program that generates HTML, or an in-browser webapp that takes an event and renders it? One answer to the latter might be React, the former probably requires a different kind of templating engine.

Comment: My personal view on this question is that it's not really suitable for StackOverflow, as the answers to this will be really opinion-based. Try to solve this problem in another language and ask how you could port it to TypeScript maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create the schema for your data. This will help you on working with TypeScript and IDE.

You can use https://app.quicktype.io which give you.

```
export interface Welcome {
    exception: Exception;
    level:     string;
}

export interface Exception {
    values: Value[];
}

export interface Value {
    stacktrace: Stacktrace;
    type:       string;
    value:      string;
    module:     string;
    mechanism:  null;
}

export interface Stacktrace {
    frames: Frame[];
}

export interface Frame {
    function:     string;
    abs_path:     string;
    pre_context:  string[];
    lineno:       number;
    vars:         Vars;
    context_line: string;
    post_context: string[];
    module:       string;
    filename:     string;
}

export interface Vars {
    exc:       string;
    local_var: string;
}
```

2. Render HTML from your `data`.

You can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) 
    if you do not have prefer web framework (React, Vue).

```
const data = JSON.parse(json);
const html = `
    <div>${data.exception.values.map(value => `
        <div>${value.stacktrace.frames.map(frame => `
            <div>
                <pre>${frame.abs_path} in ${frame.function}</pre>
                <div style="margin-left:2rem">
                    ${frame.pre_context.map((line, i) =>`
                        <pre>${frame.lineno + i - frame.pre_context.length}. ${line}</pre>
                    `).join("")}

                    <pre><strong>${frame.lineno}. ${frame.context_line}</strong></pre>
                    ${frame.post_context.map((line, i) => `
                        <pre>${frame.lineno + i + 1}. ${line}</pre>
                    `).join("")}
                </div>
            </div>
        `).join("")}</div>
    `).join("")}</div>
`;
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/52x8r17zo4

Answer (score 5):

To do this on your own without a framework I would create a class for each element in the json. Then I would have a `toHTML(domParent)` method on each class that iterated over it's sub components:

```
class Stacktrace { 
  frames: Frame[];
  type: string;
  value: string;
  module: string;
  mechanism: string;

  toHTML(domParent) {
    for (let frame of Frame) {
      frame.toHTML(domParent); 
    }
    domParent.addChild(`<div>${type}</div>`);
    domParent.addChild(`<div>${value}</div>`);
    domParent.addChild(`<div>${module}</div>`);
    domParent.addChild(`<div>${mechanism}</div>`);
  }
}
```

This is just pseudocode but should get you on the right track.

Comment: I would also recommend at least using something like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) for basic components. If you do end up wanting a framework you could do worse than picking [Angular](https://angular.io/).

Answer (score 4):

Option 1. save the file as .json and open with browser (I tried with FireFox) you should be able to see it in a very nice format as in pic posted by you.

option 2. use JavaScript to dynamically create DOM objects depending on the JSON. Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_html.asp) and [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamic-tables-json/).

/*

Following are some hints for creating your script

- parse JSON
- use recursive function to create div or p tags as per your preference.
- also add click event listener on each element to expand/collapse the child views.

*/

Hope this helps.