# convert JSON object to html table format in typescript

Tags: html, json, typescript

I am trying to convert JSON object to html table format in typescript and send using window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=subject&body="+JSON.stringify(this.Notes);

Any recommendations here

```
[
  {
    "RouteID": "r1",
    "Message": "Test2",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-06-20T14:33:27",
    "CreatedBy": "j","Replys": [
      {
        "RouteID": "r1",
        "Message": "reply1",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-06-20T14:33:54",
        "CreatedBy": "j"
      },
      {
        "RouteID": "r1",
        "Message": "reply2",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-06-20T14:34:04",
        "CreatedBy": "j"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "RouteID": "r1",
    "Message": "Test",
    "CreatedDate": "2019-06-20T14:33:21",
    "CreatedBy": "j","Replys": [
      {
        "RouteID": "r1",
        "Message": "reply3",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-06-20T14:34:11",
        "CreatedBy": "j"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: may be the answer to this SO question be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858089/convert-json-from-sentry-to-html-with-typescript

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your issue. Do you need help with the typescript interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to send an email with these data into a table in html format ?

Try this:

```
let table = 
    '<table>' +
        '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<th>RouteID</th>' +
                '<th>Message</th>' +
                '<th>CreatedDate</th>' +
                '<th>CreatedBy</th>' +
                '<th>Replys</th>'+
             '</tr>' +
         '</thead>' +
         '<tbody>' +
             '<tr>';

for(let i = 0; i < this.Notes.length; i++) {
    table += '<td>' + data[i].RouteID + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + data[i].Message + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + data[i].CreatedDate + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + data[i].CreatedBy + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + data[i].Replys + '</td>';
    if(i < this.Notes.length - 1) table += '</tr><tr>';
}
table += '</tr></tbody></table>';

// Your table is ready ! You can deal with it
console.log(table);
```

Note that your datas have nested arrays, I juste handle the first level array. You can loop through replys to concatenate content or simply transform them to string with `JSON.stringify(data[i].Replys)`